# Making changes to my data models on a production server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have recently published my mvc 5 application to a windows server using IIS.  Now I might be thinking too much into this, because when using code first it should populate the database with the new entries to my data model.  HOWEVER, before i make changes to my data model in my development environment, i just wanted to ask here to make sure I really don't mess anything up.

So after launching my application as always now my client wants me to make some changes which now involve me adding a data model as well as new controllers.  Is it safe for me to add these changes, then once i re-publish the application, should the production database get updated as per the code-first additions i've made?

I'm having some confusion in understanding how my production database is going to recognize the new data, and tables that are being added once i make this update.

Do i simply attach my newly changed database from my development machine to my production environment -  All the data on my development system is needed and usable on the production side of things as well.

I hope i was able to ask this question clear enough so that someone can help me out.

I plan to make weekly or bi-weekly changes to the web app.

Thank you

Comment: Did you define migrations for your model changes? Do you execute those migrations against the database as part of your deployment process?

Comment: I use the nuget console to make my migration updates to the dev database.  But I did notice the option to execute code first when deploying.  I will assume that will make the changes needed to my production database .  Thank you , I wasnt confident the changes would take place but it's making sense now.